# Theorem of Bukovsky characterizing ground models

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

It was mentioned in a talk that Bukovsky proved the following are equivalent for inner models $M \subseteq V$:

(1) There is a partial order $\mathbb P \in M$ and a $\mathbb P$-generic filter $G \in V$ over $M$ such that $V = M[G]$.

(2) There is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that for every ordinal $\alpha$ and every function $f : \alpha \to \mathrm{Ord}$ in $V$, there is $F : \alpha \to [\mathrm{Ord}]^{<\kappa}$ in $M$ such that $(\forall \beta < \alpha) f(\beta) \in F(\beta)$.

Is this written up somewhere?  If not, can you prove it?  (Obviously (2) $\rightarrow$ (1) is the hard part.)

Comment: Was the talk titled "Trees on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$"? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original paper is ``[Characterization of generic extensions of models of set theory](https://eudml.org/doc/214703)''

A proof can be found in the master thesis of Giorgio Audrito,  "Characterizations of set generic extensions", which is available at Viale's home page [here](http://www.logicatorino.altervista.org/matteo_viale/).

Also the paper ''On the set-generic multivers'' by Friedman-Fuchino-Sakai gives a proof. See [Friedman's home page](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~sdf/papers/).

I may mention that $\kappa$ can be chosen to be the cardinal for which the forcing notion is $\kappa$-c.c.